# Get out of named Range while inserting new text adjacent to named Range element

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, named-ranges

I have a scenario in which i want to insert some text adjacent to Named Range element, but they new inserted text should not be the part of this range, it should be in a new range, how can i achieve, currenty when i do insertText it adds the new text to the same range.

```
[Text] -> in name range
```

i called insertText('+') when cursor was after ']'

```
[Text]+
```

when i get all ranges it gives only [Text]+ what i want is

```
[ [Text], + ]
```

Answer (score 0):

### You need to create a new [named range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range)

```
var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
rangeBuilder.addElement(cursor.insertText('new Text'), 0,0);             
doc.addNamedRange('newRange', rangeBuilder.build());
```